# Goodness of fit of an approximation of a PDF

Tags: machine-learning, density-function, goodness-of-fit

I'd like to evaluate the performance of an algorithm which learns to approximate a discrete PDF for a latent variable given some noisy input.
Now, is there a standard test to evaluate the goodness of that approximation?
I would like to train the algorithm with synthetic data and then see how close the approximation is to the PDF I can compute knowing how the data was generated.

I thought of computing the Kullback-Leibler divergence, but

- I don't know what's a good value.  KL divergence is the information gain, so could I argue that eg. losing only <= 5% of the total information when using the approximation is good?
- How do I combine KL divergences from multiple trials with different input?  Can I average?  I suppose I might, considering that all the computed PDFs can be seen as one PDF over a multi-dimensional latent variable.